# NetBeans Saved SVN password

Tags: svn, netbeans, passwords

I wonder where NetBeans stores SVN password and is it encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using *NetBeans 7.1* with *CollabNet Subversion Client 1.7.5*.

I think it is saved under:

```
C:\Users\{your_user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\
```

I found a file named `b65887bc6b............` (a kind of random hash) containing some SVN connection settings. The password is encrypted, but I don't know yet where and how the encryption key is stored:

```
K 8
passtype
V 8
wincrypt
K 8
password
V 272
AQAAANCMnd8BFdE.........................etc
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 46
<https://svn.example.com:443> Example Domain Login
K 8
username
V 3
my_user_name
END
```

Comment: See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.7.8/subversion/libsvn_subr/win32_crypto.c : `windows_password_decrypter()` on how to decrypt the data. In brief, it's `base64_decode()`, then `CryptUnprotectData()` .

Answer (score 0):

If you set Global password the Yes, or it will not encrypt them see: [Master Password Dialog](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMasterPasswordDialog)